# jScrollPane flicker issue safari

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane, flicker

i'm using a jScrollPane for dynamic content.
http://dev.harvest.sugarshaker.com/#interview20  ...click on 'open transcript'

it works fine on mac firefox, but mac safari flickers when scrolled.  i've not even checked on a pc yet!  i think its a css issue, and possibly something to do with the clipping region i've added, to hide the transcipt panel.

here's how the scroll pane is created:

```
var api = null;
$(function() {     
  var pane = $('#transcript');
  pane.jScrollPane();
  api = pane.data('jsp');
});
```

then later on...

```
api.getContentPane().html(data.transcript);
api.reinitialise();
```

can anyone help?

many thanks,

rob.

Comment: I came across the exact same thing yesterday. In my case, there's an iframe to the left of the scrollpane. Unless I can find another scrollbar skinning alternative soon, I think I will revert back to the native scrollbar since jScrollPane is currently unusable for me in Safari.

Comment: What version of Safari on Mac are you using?  I tried it out in 5.0.6 and it didn't appear to be flickering...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues in OSX / Safari and solved it by updating to the latest version (v2.0.0beta12 - 2012-09-27).
Even though the version number was the same as the one with flaws in Safari, the version date and script's content were different and it now runs smoothly.